# Remove of ADD in Dockerfile

Tags: dockerfile

I created a `Dockerfile` and use the `ADD` command to download an installer and execute it so I can prepare my docker container. But I can't find a `delete` counterpart. Am I missing something?

```
# Dockerfile
ADD https://../file.zip file.exe
.. do something with file.exe
Delete file.exe
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `RUN` instead.

```
RUN rm file.exe
```